# MongoDB Aggregation and filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find events near a location within a certain category

Here's my code

```
var q=  EventModel.aggregate({
      $geoNear : {
        near: coords,
        distanceField: "distance",
        spherical:true,
        distanceMultiplier:6378,
        query : {"rubriques.id" : categorie},
        uniqueDocs: true,
        maxDistance : radius,
        limit: limit}
      });
```

Without "query" it works well, but with "query" all i get is `[]`

Any idea why ?

Thanks a lot,
Jeremie.

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around `categorie`?

Comment: categorie is a variable instantiated with `var categorie = req.query.categorie`

Comment: A bit of a guess, but [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) doesn't do any casting of query parameters based on your schema, so if `rubriques.id` is a number in your schema and docs you'd need to convert `categorie` to a number as well using `+categorie` or `parseInt(categorie, 10)`.

Comment: Yeah, try `parseInt(categorie)`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works :)